# Табы: выпадающее меню

Tags: jquery, menu

Помогите исправить выпадающее меню у табов.
Открытому табу добавляется класс .active
Сейчас выпадающее меню работает, но если покликать на табах, то табы не правильно открываются, т.е. если один таб открыт, и кликнуть по другому закрытому табу, то обе вкладки закрываются, а должно быть так, чтобы одна открылась а другая закрылась.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .wrapper{
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        .cars-nav li{
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
        .cars-nav li span{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .wrapper-drop{
            position: relative;
        }
        .drop{
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            background: #000;
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: green;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding: 20px 70px;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 100;
        }
        .outer{
            height: 500px;
        }
        .inner{
            color: #fff;
            list-style: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="view-bottom">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="cars-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="drop1">
                    <span>Tab-1</span>
                </li>
                <li class="drop2">
                    <span>Tab-2</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!--Start:Выпадающее меню-->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav id="mm-menu" class="wrapper-drop">
            <ul class="outer">
                <li class="drop" data-drop="drop1">
                    <ul class="inner">
                        <li>item1</li>
                        <li>item2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="drop" data-drop="drop2">
                    <ul class="inner">
                        <li>item3</li>
                        <li>item4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!--End:Выпадающее меню-->
</div>

<script>
    $('.view-bottom nav.cars-nav li span').on('click', function(e){
        var $target = $(e.target).closest('li'),
            dropClass = $target.attr('class'),
            $viewBottom = $('.view-bottom'),
            $parent = $target.closest('.nav');
        $('.view-bottom .drop').stop().slideUp(300).removeClass('active');
        $parent.find('li').not($target).removeClass('active');
        $target.toggleClass('active');
        $viewBottom.find('[data-drop="'+dropClass+'"]').stop().slideToggle(300).toggleClass('active');
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы идентификатор выпадающего меню записали в класс

```
<li class="drop1">
```

Затем добавляете класс `active`

```
$target.toggleClass('active');
```

И после этого пытаетесь найти выпадающее меню:

```
dropClass = $target.attr('class')
$viewBottom.find('[data-drop="'+dropClass+'"]')
```

Вы же понимаете что он ищет не `data-drop="drop1"` а `data-drop="drop1 active"`?

Почему-бы здесь не использовать data-атрибут??

```
<li data-menu="drop1">
```

И никаких проблем с классами:

```
dropClass = $target.data('menu')
```

**Исправленный сниппет:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .wrapper{
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        .cars-nav li{
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
        .cars-nav li span{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .wrapper-drop{
            position: relative;
        }
        .drop{
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            background: #000;
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: green;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding: 20px 70px;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 100;
        }
        .outer{
            height: 500px;
        }
        .inner{
            color: #fff;
            list-style: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="view-bottom">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="cars-nav">
            <ul>
                <li data-menu="drop1">
                    <span>Tab-1</span>
                </li>
                <li data-menu="drop2">
                    <span>Tab-2</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!--Start:Выпадающее меню-->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav id="mm-menu" class="wrapper-drop">
            <ul class="outer">
                <li class="drop" data-drop="drop1">
                    <ul class="inner">
                        <li>item1</li>
                        <li>item2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="drop" data-drop="drop2">
                    <ul class="inner">
                        <li>item3</li>
                        <li>item4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!--End:Выпадающее меню-->
</div>

<script>
    $('.view-bottom nav.cars-nav li span').on('click', function(e){
        var dropClass = $(this).closest('li').data('menu');
        $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
   $('.view-bottom [data-drop="'+dropClass+'"]').stop().slideToggle(300).toggleClass('active').siblings().stop().slideUp(300).removeClass('active')      

      });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ваш исправленный вариант не совсем корректно работает. т.е. если открыть инспектор кода браузера, тогда видно, что при кликах на табах, класс .active не правильно меняется

Comment: как правильно настроить меню?

Comment: Т.е. за вас исправить остальные ошибки? Переписал ваш код