# Как создать выпадающее меню при нажатии?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, меню

Объясните пожалуйста, как создается выпадающее меню при нажатии. Приму любую конструкцию, главное, чтобы работало. Нужен просто пример.

Comment: К фрилансерам обращайтесь

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Табы: выпадающее меню](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/%d0%a2%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e)

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick Тут точно не про табы. Человек лишь хотел понять принцип работы выпадающего меню. А в табах еще дата-атрибуты и т.д.

Comment: @VladSpirin Ответ может быть 100% правильным, но притянуть минусов за ответ на низкокачественный вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Без красоты, чисто принцип, как работает:

```js
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
nav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;

  var targetParent = target.closest('.menu-item');

  if (targetParent) {
    var subm = targetParent.getElementsByClassName('submenu')[0];
    close();
    if (subm) {
      subm.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
});

function close() {
  var s = document.getElementsByClassName('submenu');
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    s[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#nav {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.menu li {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.menu-item {
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.submenu-item {
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">item1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">item2</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">item2_1</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">item2_2</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">item2_3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">item3</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">item3_1</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">item3_2</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">item3_3</a>
          <!-- <ul class="submenu-level2">
              <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">item4_1</a></li>
              <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">item4_2</a></li>
              <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">item4_3</a></li>
            </ul> -->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">item4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Я вам настоятельно рекомендую перечитать, [основы работы с событиями.](https://learn.javascript.ru/events-and-interfaces)  Тут введение в браузерные события, общие свойства всех событий и приёмы работы с ними. А также ознакомиться с [документом и объектами страницы.](https://learn.javascript.ru/document)  Тут вы научитесь при помощи JavaScript получать и менять существующие элементы на странице, а также создавать новые.

Comment: А как реализовать, чтобы субменю показывалось только при нажатии?

Comment: Такой ответ вам подходит ?

Comment: Вы написали, что примете любую конструкцию, вот я и не парился со стилями и т.д., с субменю делаете по аналогу, внимательно изучите этот код. Так все меню работают. Это базовые знания JS.

Comment: Так, извиняюсь за наглость, а как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на любое пустое пространство субменю закрывалось?

Comment: еще один слушатель события навесить можно.

Comment: Изучите внимательно события в JS, без них вы вообще никуда не уедите далее.