# Как обратиться к списку который находится в двух дивах?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть список, который находится в двух дивах и к нему нужно обратиться чтобы при наведении появлялся другой список, но обычное `.class li:hover .class1` не работает, в интернете ничего подобного не нашел, что не пробовал, ничего не помогает, может есть какой-то другой способ?

```css
.dd .dd1 {
  display: none;
}

.menu li:hover .dd1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dd">
  <div class="menu-list">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <ul class="dd1">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос, можно посмотреть на html-разметку и желательно какую-нибудь картинку, а лучше две (до и после наведения)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, но из того что понял на `табы` похоже, может я и ошибаюсь, раскройте вопрос по подробнее. Тут в любом случае JS нужен.

Comment: @VladSpirin по описанию больше походит на выпадающие списки с дочерними списками.

Comment: @Vlad Spirin, скорее на Popup Menu

Comment: [Вот вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780546/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8/780549#780549), простой, но главное смысл, это если меню. Но мы ж не должны тут в догадки играть, пусть автор проявит активность. Просто я вначале понял, что есть два `<div>` и в них два отдельных списка.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин, нажмите у вопроса кнопку "править" и вставьте код в вопрос, а не в комментарий

Comment: Извините что туплю, первый раз тут и плохо понимаю что да как.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин, ну через два блока пройти `.dd > .list > .dd1`, либо указывать первого, либо просто `.dd .dd1`, возможно если нужно первый элемент, то `:nth-child(1)`...

Comment: @entithat Не работает так, пробовал ранее

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин как именно?

Comment: @entithat .dd > .list > .dd1 вот так. Смысл задумки в том что я изначально прячу список_0 и при наведении на список_1, список_0 должен появляться но этого никак не удается реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял из вопроса, необходимо, чтобы при наведении на список `.menu-list` появлялся список `.list`. Вот рабочий пример:

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}

.menu-list:hover~.list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dd">
  <div class="menu-list">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <ul class="dd1">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы наверное заметили что список_0 появляется не только если навести на список_1, но и если просто навести мышку в любое место на уровне списка_1, а нужно чтобы он появлялся лишь при точном наведении на видимый список.

Comment: Блоки тянутся на всю ширину родителя. Установи максимальную ширину, например, `max-width: 150px` для родителя `.dd` и будет тебе счастье.